# Set variable in generate:before hook with Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I've successfully gotten a `generate:before` hook inside of `nuxt.config.js` to make a request and return the result I'm looking for. **How can I set a variable of some sort that can be displayed in a view when the site is generated?**

Ideally I could set the vuex state with the variable, or set a process.env variable which could be easily displayed by the frontend.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1):

[nuxtServerInit](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store#the-nuxtserverinit-action) ended up being what I was looking for in this case.